# Computer Algebra/Symbolic Computing: Algorithm to determine if real function is nonnegative

Tags: algorithms, real-numbers, computer-algebra-systems, symbolic-computation

Suppose I have a function $f:[a, b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R},~a,b\in \mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$. Is there any Computer\Algebra or Symbolic Computing algorithm to determine if $f$ is nonnegative?

For starters, lets suppose $f$ is integrable, continuous and differentiable.

If the answer is negative, what about particular cases of the problem (Rationals, Integer, limited or finite image)?

Comment: $\int_{a}^{b}\left[\mathrm{f}\left(x\right) - \left\vert\mathrm{f}\left(x\right)\right\vert\right]\,\mathrm{d}x = 0$

Comment: Mmm... that should work. Will try that. Netx time I should probably think a more than 30 seconds about the issue before asking.

Do you have any experience attempting that at a CAS (or a reference to someone who did)?

Comment: $0$ k. I just did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One possible test is given by
$$
\int_{a}^{b}\left[\mathrm{f}\left(\, x\,\right) - \left\vert\mathrm{f}\left(\, x\,\right)\right\vert\right]dx = 0
$$

Comment: Is the function continuous?  For example, discontinuous function $\lfloor x \rfloor - \lceil x \rceil$ meets this integral test.